# Return a defined range of characters in Go

Tags: regex, go

Let's say we have a converted float to a string:

```
"24.22334455667"
```

I want to just return 6 of the digits on the right of the decimal

I can get all digits, after the decimal this way:

```
re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`[!.]([\d]+)$`)
```

But I want only the first 6 digits after the decimal but this returns nothing:

```
re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`[!.]([\d]{1,6})$`)
```

How can I do this? I could not find an example of using `[\d]{1,6}`

Thanks

Comment: I think, here better not use regex. Show this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390266/how-can-we-truncate-float64-type-to-a-particular-precision-in-golang and then converting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the end of the line anchor `$` since it won't be a line end after exactly 6 digits. For to capture exactly 6 digits, the quantifier must be

```
re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`[!.](\d{6})`)
```

Note that, this would also the digits which exists next to `!`. If you don't want this behaviour, you must remove the `!` from the charcater class like

```
re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`[.](\d{6})`)
```

**or**

For to capture digits ranges from 1 to 6,

```
re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`[!.](\d{1,6})`)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively...

```
func DecimalPlaces(decimalStr string, places int) string {
    location := strings.Index(decimalStr, ".")
    if location == -1 {
        return ""
    }
    return decimalStr[location+1 : min(location+1+places, len(decimalStr))]
}
```

Where min is just a simple function to find the minimum of two integers.

Regular expressions seem a bit heavyweight for this sort of simple string manipulation.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/gDdwtmvkLB)